# BiometricPrompt.authenticate() with custom screen

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

I've migrated our app from the deprecated FingerprintManager to `Biometric API`. The app currently has a custom fragment which actually acts like the new `BiometricPrompt`. I would like to continue using this custom page thus not showing the BiometricPrompt. Problem is that the way to activate authentication is by creating this prompt and showing it.

```
biometricPrompt.authenticate(BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle("Title text goes here")
        .setSubtitle("Subtitle goes here")
        .setDescription("This is the description")
        .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
        .build()
)
```

How can I avoid displaying the BiometricPrompt and just activate authentication?

PS:
On my OnePlus6T the prompt actually doesn't show because the of the device's on-screen fingerprint scanning, but on all others the prompt is shown.

Comment: Unfortunately you can not do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. BiometricPrompt is the new uniformed request dialog for fingerprint

See Android 9 ChangeLog https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0?source=post_page-----d4fc85e55608----------------------#biometric-auth

For OnePlus is a bug
https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/problems-about-oneplus-6t-fingerprint-api.944959/